# Merging code from two SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to combine the contents of two separate (but very closely related) sql queries, but am finding it difficult to get something that doesn't return syntax errors.

The two queries that are currently working are

```
SELECT module.ModuleCode,
       demonstrator.FK_Course,
       slot.fk_ModuleCode,
       programme.C_val,
       Count(slotdemo.FK_Demonstrator) AS CountOfFK_Demonstrator
FROM programme
INNER JOIN (demonstrator
            INNER JOIN (((module
                          INNER JOIN slot ON module.ModuleCode = slot.fk_ModuleCode))
                        INNER JOIN slotdemo ON slot.SlotNo = slotdemo.FK_SlotNo) ON demonstrator.StudentID = slotdemo.FK_Demonstrator) ON programme.COURSE = demonstrator.FK_Course
WHERE demonstrator.`undergraduate`=1
GROUP BY module.ModuleCode
```

and

```
SELECT week.Hour,
       module.color,
       module.moduleName,
       module.num_ugdemos,
       slot.fk_Room,
       slot.fk_ModuleCode,
       slottime.FK_Hour,
       slottime.FK_SlotNo,
       programme.C_val,
       Count(slotdemo.FK_Demonstrator) AS CountOfFK_Demonstrator
FROM week
INNER JOIN ((programme
             INNER JOIN ((module
                          INNER JOIN slot ON module.ModuleCode = slot.fk_ModuleCode)
                         INNER JOIN slottime ON slot.SlotNo = slottime.FK_SlotNo) ON programme.COURSE = module.FK_Course)
            LEFT JOIN slotdemo ON slot.SlotNo = slotdemo.FK_SlotNo) ON week.Hour = slottime.FK_Hour
GROUP BY week.Hour,
         module.ModuleCode,
         module.moduleName,
         module.color,
         slot.SlotNo,
         slot.fk_Room,
         slottime.FK_Hour,
         programme.C_val HAVING((programme.C_val)<9);
```

my preliminary attempt at combining the two is

```
SELECT
       week.Hour,
       module.color,
       module.moduleName,
       module.num_ugdemos,
       slot.fk_Room,
       slot.fk_ModuleCode,
       slottime.FK_Hour,
       slottime.FK_SlotNo,
       programme.C_val,
       Count(slotdemo.FK_Demonstrator) AS CountOfFK_Demonstrator
FROM
    week
INNER JOIN
(
    (
        programme
    INNER JOIN
        (
            demonstrator
        INNER JOIN
            (
                (
                    (
                        module
                    INNER JOIN
                        slot
                            ON module.ModuleCode = slot.fk_ModuleCode
                    )
                )
            INNER JOIN
                slotdemo
                    ON slot.SlotNo = slotdemo.FK_SlotNo
            )
                ON demonstrator.StudentID = slotdemo.FK_Demonstrator
        )
            ON programme.COURSE = demonstrator.FK_Course
    )
        ON week.Hour = slottime.FK_Hour
WHERE
    demonstrator.`undergraduate`=1
GROUP BY week.Hour,
         module.moduleName,
         module.color,
         slot.SlotNo,
         slot.fk_ModuleCode,
         slot.fk_Room,
         slottime.FK_Hour,
         programme.C_val
```

The error message, for what's it's worth (which is not much) is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON week.Hour = slottime.FK_Hour WHERE
>   demonstrator.undergraduate=1 GROUP BY we' at line 17

Comment: Pls describe what you would like to achive here. Sample source data and results were also not amiss!

Comment: Remove the `(` in the `INNER JOIN` parts. Those are not needed.

Comment: @Shadow I was tempted to... but it would be reinventing the wheel in this case (I believe this to be 95% of a solution to quite a tricky problem). It would take a while to explain and understand the overall logical problem, while I think that the only limiting factor now is syntactic.

Comment: @Stumbler then I'm voting to close this question for being unclear. No description of what you would like to achive, no exact error message that would indicate where in the sql statement mysql has found an error.

Comment: @Shadow I want to write the joins of the above query correctly so as to combine the logic of the two preceding, working, sql queries. The error message, for what's it's worth (which is not much) is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON week.Hour = slottime.FK_Hour
WHERE demonstrator.`undergraduate`=1
GROUP BY we' at line 17

Comment: There are 6 opening and only 5 closing brackets in the join condition where the message indicates the place of the syntax error. Since I have no idea what you wanna do, I cannot fix it for you.

Comment: @Stumbler - I've edited your post to use more standard indenting.  This makes it very clear that you have both redundant and missing paranthesis.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to UNION Two datasets together. Just use the UNION operator:

```
(SELECT .... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT ... FROM t2)
```

Both selects should return the same columns, IF the names differ you can use `AS` to rename it.